# Format for a deep link in Slack

Tags: slack-api

I have some webhooks setup on a few slack channels. I want them to post deep links to other apps that people can click on when they are using Slack on their mobile device. The format for a regular link is

```
< url | display_name > (in String form)
```

but that doesn't work for deep links. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

That format that you posted should work. The only difference between yours and mine, is that mine doesn't include spaces between the `<|>` chars. For example, this is how I link to a specific ad in the Facebook marketing dashboard:

```
`Ad: <${link}|${title}>`
```

Which expands to something like:

```
"Ad: <https://business.facebook.com/ads/manager/adset/ads/?act=my-account&ids=the-adset-id|The Ad's Title>"
```

Comment: Just noticed that the question is nearly a year old. Maybe this didn't work back then.

Answer (score 0):

I used `slack://` scheme like `<slack://user?team=Txxx&id=Uxxx|open user profile>`.

It worked, but Slack asked me if I wanted to use this scheme to open Slack application ‍♂️